# gcloud nodejs download app

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

i have a gcloud nodejs app and i deployed. i want to download app (not clone) because i want to check 'uploads' folder. This 'uploads' folder contains uploaded images and images uploaded via multer.js

My main problem: generally uploaded images return 404 (but well works in local)

for example:
https://mobil-pet.appspot.com/static/2018-04-15T18-01-10.120ZmyImage-1523815269060.jpg

also i get error with 404:

[image]

this is my code for render uploads:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('uploads'));
```

this is my package.js:

[image]

i need help, thanks

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Thanks.

Comment: Is your upload directory shared across your app instances?

Comment: I fixed uploads (i used bucket) but I still have not found how to download the application

Answer (score 1):

There is no GAE generic way to download the application's dynamically stored data.

Since you now have a GCS bucket shared by all your instances to store the uploaded data you can directly access it using the developer console, the `gsutil` utility or programmatically, see [Listing Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) and [Downloading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects).

Another possible approach (but less convenient IMHO) would be by [Connecting to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance) and accessing the data locally.